# Track each request to the website using HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, web, request, analytics, tracking

I want to save each request to the website. In general I want to include the following information:

1. User IP, The web site url, user-if-exist, date-time.
2. Response time, response success-failed status.

Is it reasonable to collect the 1 and 2 in the same action? (like same HttpModule)?

Do you know about any **existing** structure that I can follow that track every request/response-status to the website?

The data need to be logged to sql server.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosag/default.aspx

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.  Question should be "how do I configure IIS to post logs to sql server."

Comment: But IIS obviously cannot link between logs to the user that made the request.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your web server logs.

Comment: The data need to be logged to sql server.

Comment: You can configure iis to post the logs to a sql server instead of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

How about IIS logs? they already have all the data items you listed so far

Comment: Don't HttpModule better solution? How the IIS can know bout error, if the error will never be shown to the user? Can you have any link?

Comment: No it is not. Some requests will never get to ASP.NET process - i.e. bad urls (HTTP 404) and the such. Also the response is always sent back. It may be hidden by the browser behind a pretty (but useless) screen, but it will be there and in the logs

Answer (score 0):

In BeginRequest Method you need to write the following code.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //String s = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
        //HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Login.aspx");
        String referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;
        String sourceIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        String browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
    }
```